# Can Containing be used on a list in Spring Data?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have `documents` (using `mongodb`) which has a list of `ObjectId` as one of the variables and I wanna filter those documents based on if this list contains a certain element, so I was wondering if `Containing` works as well on lists (`findByListContaining(id)` ), I couldn't find anything regarding lists, only `String`.

Thanks.

```
Class FooClass{

List<ObjectId> barIds;
}
```

Comment: show your document class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example on spring-data-mongodb [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/PersonRepository.java)

Look at this method specifically

```
Person findByShippingAddresses(Address address);
```

shippingAddress is defined as

```
private Set<Address> shippingAddresses;
```

In Person class. Which means it works for List as well.

In your case a method like this should work

```
findByBarIds(ObjectId barId)
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, I know how to do IN.